# JavaFX rectangle width animation

Tags: animation, width, javafx-8, rectangles

just a question... is it possible to show the change of the width of a rectangle as an animation? The rectangle itself is a statusbar so a scale in both x directions does not do the job.

thx

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to animate the width modification within a [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) as opposed to scaling in both directions. You can simulate the direction by modifying the alignment of the `Rectangle`'s parent

Alignment values:

- `Pos.CENTER` : Appears as though the change is occurring in both directions
- `Pos.CENTER_LEFT`: Appears as though the change is occurring from the right
- `Pos.CENTER_RIGHT`: Appears as though the change is occurring from the left

By experimenting with alignments you can choose the one that best fits your current status bar

---

Visual representation:

Order of alignment:    `Right | Center | Left`

[image: right]
[image: center]
[image: left]

---

SSCCE:

```
public class RectangleWidthAnimation extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Rectangle statusBar = new Rectangle(300, 100);
        Button animationButton = new Button("Animate width decrease by 25");
        animationButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Animation start: width = " + statusBar.getWidth());
            KeyValue widthValue = new KeyValue(statusBar.widthProperty(), statusBar.getWidth() - 25);
            KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), widthValue);
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(frame);
            timeline.play();
            timeline.setOnFinished(finishedEvent -> System.out.println("Animation end: width = " + statusBar.getWidth()));
        });

        VBox container = new VBox(10, statusBar, animationButton);

        //Experiment with these alignments
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        //container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        //container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(container, 350, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

An alternative to the above could be to use transitions, which you can read about [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm#BEIIJJJB)